# Input string was not in a correct format with DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a DatePicker from whose value I am trying to insert to an SQL Server table's **Date** field.

```
tbl_leave_student updateStdLeave = new tbl_leave_student{
                leave_from=Convert.ToDateTime( dpLeaveFromStd.SelectedDate.GetValueOrDefault())
            };
            db.tbl_leave_students.InsertOnSubmit(updateStdLeave);
            db.SubmitChanges();
```

This gives a Format Exception with the message

> Input string was not in a correct format

I've tried inserting without the `Convert.ToDateTime` and also `dpLeaveFromStd.SelectedDate (without the .GetValueOrDefault())` and got the same error. Any reason why?

Comment: you have to specify the format of the date as well like `yyyy-MM-dd`..

Comment: specify your input string

Comment: I guess you are using a Nullable DatePicker so you should be getting the values as DateTime, so try just using `SelectedDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now);`

Comment: Why are u converting `dpLeaveFromStd` to DateTime it is DateTime picker and alway have value Date, use `dpLeaveFromStd.Value.Date` instate

Comment: My dpLeaveFromStd does not have a .Value

Comment: and none of the solutions worked so far

Comment: What type of application (asp.net, WPF, winform ..) ? and what is the datetime picker you are  using?

Comment: WPF. and the datepicker is from system.windows.controls

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using a Nullable DatePicker and probably you would be getting a null value,

So you should try to modify the code as

```
leave_from = dpLeaveFromStd.SelectedDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now);
```

So this would set it to a default to Today if the value is null

Answer (score 1):

you can do as below

```
leave_from = dpLeaveFromStd.SelectedDate ?? DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should always use D[ateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx).

```
string[] formats = { "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy" };  //your format here
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dpLeaveFromStd.SelectedDate.GetValueOrDefault(), formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{

}
```